# Bulk insert query + Embedded Entity + JPA +Hibernet

Tags: hibernate, jpa, ejb-3.1

I need to write bulk insert query on Entity which has embedded primary key

I have following entity,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MAP_SCHEDULE_LOB")
public class MapScheduleLob implements java.io.Serializable {
   private MapScheduleLobId id;

    @EmbeddedId
@AttributeOverrides( {
        @AttributeOverride(name = "scheduleReferenceId", column = @Column(name = "SCHEDULE_REFERENCE_ID", nullable = false, precision = 38, scale = 0)),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "lobCode", column = @Column(name = "LOB_CODE", nullable = false, length = 30)),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "sapThreadStatus", column = @Column(name = "SAP_THREAD_STATUS", nullable = false))
        })
public MapScheduleLobId getId() {
    return this.id;
}

   public void setId(MapScheduleLobId id) {
    this.id = id;
}

}
```

Below is my Embedded Entity,

```
@Embeddable
public class MapScheduleLobId implements java.io.Serializable{
    private Long scheduleReferenceId;
private String lobCode;//default

   public MapScheduleLobId(Long scheduleReferenceId, String lobCode) {
    this.scheduleReferenceId = scheduleReferenceId;
    this.setLobCode(lobCode);
    this.setSapThreadStatus(0);
}


@Column(name = "SCHEDULE_REFERENCE_ID", nullable = false, precision = 38, scale = 0)
public Long getScheduleReferenceId() {
    return this.scheduleReferenceId;
}

public void setScheduleReferenceId(Long scheduleReferenceId) {
    this.scheduleReferenceId = scheduleReferenceId;
}

@Column(name="LOB_CODE",nullable=false,length = 30)
public String getLobCode() {
    return lobCode;
}

public void setLobCode(String lobCode) {
    this.lobCode = lobCode;
}


}
```

Now I have execute below JPQL query like,

insert into MapScheduleLob (scheduleReferenceId,lobCode) select new      com.eks.srs.service.schedule.entity.MapScheduleLobId(model.id.scheduleReferenceId,model.lobCode) from DownloadScheduleView model where model.id.scheduleReferenceId =10

It gives me exception. If I do not have Embedded Key then above query worked.

So can anyone help how to write bulk insert query with Embedded Key.

I have used, EJB 3.1 with JPA, Hibernate 4 and Jboss 7.2.

Comment: What was the exception?

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.ejb3unit.hibernate.QueryException: number of select types did not match those for insert

Comment: I have tried various queries but all are either above exception comes or can only generate ids as part of bulk insert with either sequence or post-insert style generators.